# How do I check for overflow after an Interlocked.Increment in C#?

Tags: c#, integer-overflow, interlocked, interlocked-increment

**What is the correct way to check for an overflow after a call to `Interlocked.Increment`?**

I have an ID generator that generates unique ids during the program's execution, and currently I test if the increment returned zero.

```
public static class IdGenerator {
    private static int _counter = 0;
    
    public static uint GetNewId() {
        uint newId = (uint)System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref _counter);
        if (newId == 0) {
             throw new System.Exception("Whoops, ran out of identifiers");
        }
        return newId;
    }
}
```

Given the rather large number of IDs that I generate per run, it is possibile (on an exceptionally large input) that the `_counter` will overflow when incremented, and I want to throw an exception in that case (crash early to ease debugging).

Excerpt from [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c.aspx):

> This method handles an overflow condition by wrapping: if `location` = `Int32.MaxValue`, `location + 1` = `Int32.MinValue`. No exception is thrown.

Comment: Consider using `long`.

Comment: Note that `(uint)int.MinValue` throws.

Comment: @SLaks (your last comment) Well, `(uint)int.MinValue` as a literal won't compile. But a non-const variable or expression `int i = int.MinValue` which hits the conversion `(uint)i` will not throw in the usual `unchecked` context.

Comment: @SLaks Thanks, I didn't think of that, the cast should be wrapped with `unchecked`, like this: `unchecked((uint)int.MinValue)` I suppose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just check whether `newId` is `Int32.MinValue` (before casting to `uint`) and throw an exception.

The only way to get `MinValue` from an increment is through overflow.

Comment: What if two threads incremented the value in short succession?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Then one of them will overflow and the other won't.  The whole point of `Interlocked.Increment` is that it's atomic; that isn't a problem.

Comment: Ah, sure, you tell him to check the return value from `Increment`, not the actual value of `_counter` field. I agree with you, then. But he should get rid of his conversion to `uint`, or something.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: `newId` _is_ the returned value from `Increment()`.

Comment: You were right, there was no issue there. __Something else:__ As his code stands in the question, he just re-interpretes the 32-bit signed integer as an _unsigned_ 32-bit integer, and he is able to get IDs up to `4'294'967'295`. So his original code worked well, if we assume that he doesn't build his code with `/checked` compiler option. If he uses your answer, he can generate only (roughly) half the IDs he could before.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `unchecked`

```
public static class IdGenerator
{
    private static int _counter;

    public static uint GetNewId()
    {
        uint newId = unchecked ((uint) System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref _counter));
        if (newId == 0)
        {
            throw new System.Exception("Whoops, ran out of identifiers");
        }
        return newId;
    }
}
```

In this case you get

1. Little performance boost, because compiler won't check overflow.
2. x2 space for keys
3. Simpler and smaller code